# Volume target in docker does not matter ? Any folder in the container seems to be persistant

Tags: docker

I don't understand.

I created a Volume for my container and then I did this to run it:

```
docker run -d --name myContainer --mount source=myVolume,target=/home -ti some_image
```

So, we agree that it is mounted on the *myVolume* with a target for the mount being the "*home*" directory.

But then, if I create anything outside the *home* directory, for instance I created **somerandomfolder** in **/var**

If I shut down the container and come back, **somerandomfolder**  is still here! But I thought only things into **/home** would be kept... why is it not the case?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "shut down"? Which command do you use to stop the container? A container loss all its data (except for explicit "volumes") when it is destroyed. Stopping/restarting the same container won't delete data. If you destroy your container and then create a new one, then only volumes data will be kept

Comment: okkkk, now I understand, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Docker, when you create a volume and mount it into a container, the data within that volume persists even if you **remove** the container. The key concept here is that the data in the volume is independent of the container's lifecycle.

In your example, you created a Docker volume named **myVolume** and mounted it into the container at the `/home` directory. This means that anything you create within the `/home` directory in the container will be stored in the **myVolume** volume. However, any changes or files you create outside of the `/home` directory in the container, such as the **somerandomfolder** in `/var`, will not be stored in the volume.

In summary, Docker volumes are designed to persist data across **container removals** only for the data specifically placed into the mounted directory or its subdirectories within the container. Changes made outside of that directory are not included in the volume and will not persist.